# OData filter for string array (Collection)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

Having API out like below, I need to apply Odata filter an string array using postman.

Need to do any C# codes or the filter is enough? Actually the Category is String[].

```
{ 
    "value": [
     {
            "Id": "10",
            "Name": "A1",
            "Category": ["a", "b"]
    },
    {
            "Id": "11",
            "Name": "A2",
            "Category": ["c", "b"]
    },
    {
            "Id": "13",
            "Name": "A3",
            "Category": ["d", "f"]
    }
]
}
```

Need to filter category 'b' and output should

```
{ 
    "value": [
     {
            "Id": "10",
            "Name": "A1",
            "Category": ["a", "b"]
    },
    {
            "Id": "11",
            "Name": "A2",
            "Category": ["c", "b"]
    } 
]
}
```

Could you please anyone help with OData filter?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description since the Category is a string array. To filter data, you could use the `any` operator. Please refer the following sample code:

1. create a CategoryInfo.cs:

   ```
    public class CategoryInfo
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string[] Category { get; set; }
    }
   ```
2. Add the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData` NuGet package to the project, and configure the OData.

   ```
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            ...
            services.AddControllers(mvcOptions =>
                mvcOptions.EnableEndpointRouting = false);

            services.AddOData(); 
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        { 
            ...
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseMvc(routeBuilder =>
            {
                routeBuilder.Select().Filter();
                routeBuilder.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "odata", GetEdmModel());
                routeBuilder.MapRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            }); 
        }
        IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
        {
            var odataBuilder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
            odataBuilder.EntitySet<CategoryInfo>("ToDo");

            return odataBuilder.GetEdmModel();
        }
    }
   ```
3. Add `[EnableQuery()]` to the API action method:

   ```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ToDoController : ControllerBase
    {
        // GET: api/<ToDoController>
        [EnableQuery()]
        [HttpGet] 
        public IEnumerable<CategoryInfo> Get()
        {
            return new List<CategoryInfo>()
            {
                new CategoryInfo(){ Id=10, Name = "A1", Category= new string[]{"a","b"}},
                new CategoryInfo(){ Id=11, Name = "A2", Category= new string[]{"c","b"}},
                new CategoryInfo(){ Id=12, Name = "A3", Category= new string[]{"d","f"}}
            };
        }
   ```
4. Use Postman to check the following request:

   ```
    https://localhost:44339/odata/ToDo?$filter=Category/any(d:contains(d, 'b'))
   ```

   The result like this (Please note the **case-sensitive**):

   [image]

Reference:

[Sample: Build web APIs with OData support using ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/webapi/first-odata-api)

[Experimenting with OData in ASP.NET Core 3.1](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/odata/experimenting-with-odata-in-asp-net-core-3-1/)

[Case Insensitive Search Filter in OData ASP.NET Core 2.0 Web API as an OWIN Middleware](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1227943/Case-Insensitive-Search-Filter-in-OData-ASP-NET-Co)